# Fast way to check for duplicates in large sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table with more than 200,000 rows that I only need to check the last few thousand rows for duplicates (not all) before I insert a new row into. Currently I'm running this query for each row I want to add:

```
SELECT ID from table where date='' and time=''
```

And based on the response from that query I write the row if the response is empty.

The issue I have with doing this is that it takes a very long time, and as the database grows this only increases how long it takes.

I tried using `LIMIT and OFFSET` by saying `SELECT ID from table where date='' and time='' limit 200000,18446744073709551615` which I thought would only search through rows after 200,000 to the end of the database however running this query doesn't seem to be any faster.

My question is this: Is there a more efficient way to "skip ahead" in the database and only search a portion of the rows instead of all of the rows?

Comment: did you create index for the table? did you make your field UNIQUE?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know better how to use code blocks.

Comment: A table with 200,000 rows is teeny tiny. MySQL should be able to search that almost instantly if you have proper indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `INSERT IGNORE`, and using a UNIQUE constraint on the table based on the columns that should be unique.

When using `INSERT IGNORE`, MySQL will automatically detect if the row is unique, and ignore the entry into the database. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) for more information.

Additionally, searching a multi-million row database should be fast as long as you have the correct indexes on the table. You should not need to search a sub-set of data (Without keys, the database will be forced to do a row-scan, which could cause the delays you're talking about).

- See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069738/optimizing-mysql-query-to-avoid-scanning-a-lot-of-rows) for some additional ideas.
- See also [Avoiding Full Table Scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html).

Comment: I'm searching for documentation on `INSERT IGNORE` and haven't yet found how it compares for duplicates. Does it check every column?

Comment: @ez4nick It compares for duplicates based on UNIQUE indexes (Remember, 1 index can cover multiple columns on the table). Add an index on the table that encompasses all the data that should be unique.